# mvc WebApi Attribute Routing produces a 405

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am getting a 405 Method Not Allowed message when adding a WebApi controller to my project.

I have this in my web config;

```
 <remove name="WebDAV" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

My WebApiConfig is;

```
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

and my method is;

```
 public class CustomerQuotationController : ApiController
{

    [Route("api/CustomerQuotation/{id}")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage AddQuotation(int id)
    {     
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created);
    }
}
```

All the help I can find says that something else is intercepting the method verb. The common culprit is WebDav, but that has been removed. So how do I identify what else could be intercepting the Put or Post calls?

the url I am using is;

```
http://localhost:2846/api/CustomerQuotation/1
```

Comment: Show the url that you are getting the error with

Comment: This sounds like an issue with CORS. Try allowing cors in your startup configuration: app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

Comment: I have included CORS in my project, but I cannot enable it in the WebAPIConfig.Register or Application_Start methods, assume I am missing a namespace, or another piece of the jigsaw. (Infact, config does not include the enableCors method, so I am definitely missing something

Comment: I have cors up and running, but still no joy.

Comment: Having problems recreating your issue. I created a project and configured just as you have shown in your post. I was able to post to the url and successful. If I tried to do a get the appropriate response was returned.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll create a new project and try again in case theres somethign else hanging around from my other attempts to solve this earlier

Comment: Are you trying this url http://localhost:2846/api/CustomerQuotation/1 in browser or you are trying to make post request programmatically?

Comment: Could you use Fiddler to capture the request and the response and add it to the question?

Comment: Originally I was using the browser, been a long week, and i made that elementary mistake. Once I realised that if I enabled all verbs it was working, I realised my mistake, and I made a quick test program to send the requests, thanks.